# Add character then remove character based on condition in string

Tags: r

1. Column con_peak: If the value contains "L" then add a "-" at the beginning of the value then remove "L".
2. Column con_peak: If the value contains "R" then remove "R".
3. Convert the column to numeric

Current column
con_peak
1.2 L
18.6 R

Desired result
con_peak
-1.2
+18.6

[image]

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). Images are not the right way to share data/code.

Answer (score 3):

We can remove the one or more spaces (`\\s+`) followed by the letters (`\\D+` or `[A-Z]+`) at the end (`$`) of the string with `sub`, then using `grepl` to find the 'L' letter in original column, `paste` the `-` with 'v1' or else return 'v1', convert to `numeric` with `as.numeric`

```
v1 <- sub("\\s+\\D+$", "", df1$con_peak)
df1$con_peak <- with(df1, as.numeric(ifelse(grepl("L", 
              con_peak), paste0("-", v1), v1)))
```

---

Or another option is with `sub` and `chartr`

```
 as.numeric(sub("^([0-9.]+)\\s+([-+])$", "\\2\\1", chartr("LR", 
            "-+", df1$con_peak)
[1]  -1.2  18.6  -4.4  -7.7 -11.9  -2.4  -5.0
```

---

Or a similar option with `trimws`

```
as.numeric(trimws(sub("^([0-9.]+)\\s+(L)", "-\\1", df1$con_peak), whitespace = "\\s+R"))
[1]  -1.2  18.6  -4.4  -7.7 -11.9  -2.4  -5.0
```

---

Or using `parse_number`

```
library(readr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df1 <- df1 %>%
    mutate(con_peak = c(1, -1)[str_detect(con_peak, "L") + 1] * 
             parse_number(con_peak))
```

-output

```
df1
con_peak
1     -1.2
2     18.6
3     -4.4
4     -7.7
5    -11.9
6     -2.4
7     -5.0
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(con_peak = c("1.2 L", "18.6 R", "4.4 L", "7.7 L", 
"11.9 L", "2.4 L", "5 L")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be done by a nested `sub` operation:

```
as.numeric(sub("(.+)\\sL$", "-\\1", sub("\\sR", "", df1$con_peak)))
[1]  -1.2  18.6  -4.4  -7.7 -11.9  -2.4  -5.0
```

The first `sub` removes whitespace followed by `R`, the second removes whitespace followed by `L`and adds a `-`in front; the result is converted to numeric by `as.numeric`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a vectorized base R way.

```
L <- grep("L$", df1$con_peak)
df1$con_peak <- as.numeric(sub("\\b\\w$", "", df1$con_peak))
df1$con_peak[L] <- -1*df1$con_peak[L]

df1
#  con_peak
#1     -1.2
#2     18.6
#3     -4.4
#4     -7.7
#5    -11.9
#6     -2.4
#7     -5.0
```

Data in [akrun's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68333360/8245406) post.